# Add new outlet in pantry to one of the two existing 20 amp small appliance branch circuits

Tags: electrical, kitchens, code-compliance

I am doing some remodeling in my kitchen. I currently have the required two 20-amp small appliance branch circuits powering the kitchen counter outlets. I have a small pantry/closet directly off the kitchen area and I would like to add an outlet or two in there. Can I hang those additional outlets off one of the two existing small appliance branch circuits?

Comment: Yeah I was wondering about that because it just says no other outlets but I don't know if that means that a pantry is considered part of the kitchen or not because another area says "These circuits may also supply receptacle outlets in the pantry, dining room, 
and breakfast room, as well as an electric clock receptacle and electric loads associated with gas-fired 
appliances, but these circuits are to have no other outlets."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ## National Electrical Code 2014
>
> ### Chapter 2 Wiring and Protection
>
> ### *Article 210 Branch Circuits*
>
> #### III. Required Outlets
>
> **210.52 Dwelling Unit Receptacle Outlets.**
>
> **(B) Small Appliances.**
>
> **(1) Receptacle Outlets Served.** In the kitchen, pantry, breakfast room, dining room, or similar area of a dwelling unit, the two or more 20-ampere small-appliance branch circuits required by 210.11(C)(1) shall serve all wall and floor receptacle outlets covered by 210.52(A), all countertop outlets covered by 210.52(C), and receptacle outlets for refrigeration equipment.
>
> **(2) No Other Outlets.** The two or more small-appliance branch circuits specified in 210.52(B)(1) shall have no other outlets.
>
> **(3) Kitchen Receptacle Requirements.** Receptacles installed in a kitchen to serve countertop surfaces shall be supplied by not fewer than two small-appliance branch circuits, either or both of which shall also be permitted to supply receptacle outlets in the same kitchen and in other rooms specified in 210.52(B)(1). Additional small-appliance branch circuits shall be permitted to supply receptacle outlets in the kitchen and other rooms specified in 210.52(B)(1). No small-appliance branch circuit shall serve more than one kitchen.

So if this is really a "pantry", and is considered a pantry by the AHJ (Authority Having Jurisdiction). Then yes, you can supply the receptacles in the pantry with the one or more small appliance circuits.

<sub>***NOTE:** There is no official definition for "pantry" in the NEC.*</sub>